# Viewing dynamic type in Netbeans debugger for C++

Tags: c++, debugging, netbeans-8

I have a class hierarchy which starts with

```
class Command { ... }
```

and then has subclasses

```
class RunCommand : public Command { ... }
```

In the Netbeans debugger, when viewing a variable of type `Command *` I would like to see the *actual* type of the variable,

```
Command * command [RunCommand]
```

and then be able to expand the field to view the state. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some research and it seems like NetBeans does not have such built in functionality.

Not to worry!  You can achieve the same effect by setting up a custom watch point for the variable you want to find out the type of.

The code that I will be debugging:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Command {
public:
   virtual void bla() {
        cout << "Base";
    }
};
class RunCommand : public Command {
public:
    void bla() {
        cout << "Child";
    }
};
int main(int argc, char** argv) {    
    Command * base_command = new Command();
    Command * run_command = new RunCommand();   
    cout << "Breakpoint"; 
    delete base_command;
    delete run_command;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I have included `<typeinfo>`.  I will be stopping to look at the variables at the line printing "Breakpoint".
Here is how the watch point looks like:
[image]

The watch expression are :

```
typeid(*base_command).__name
typeid(*run_command).__name
```

***How it works***:

I am using the [typeid operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid). I am passing it the object that I want to view the type of. Note that in our case we have to dereference the pointer to get to the object. The operator returns some kind of `typeid` object with member `__name`. That field seems to contain the runtime type of the object that is passed to `typeid`.

I am not aware how portable this is. I have done the above using NetBeans 8.0.2 and gcc 4.8.2.